# Tenho um Show Modal , e preciso colocar na mesma linha 2 dados da tabela

Tags: php, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```
$resultado .= '<dt class="col-sm-3">Cidade/Estado</dt>';
$resultado .= '<dd class="col-sm-9">'.$row_user['cidade'] .$row_user['estado'].'</dd>';
```

o resultado no Modal sai assim:

**Cidade/Estado   BetimMG**

Não consigo colocar um espaço entre Betim e MG

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa colocar o carctere `' '` (espaço) na sua string, mas você apenas deu espaço no seu código oq não afeta em nada o resultado final da string.

tente isso:

```
$resultado .= '<dd class="col-sm-9">' . $row_user['cidade'] . ' ' . $row_user['estado'] . '</dd>';
```

se por algum motivo o navegador ignorar o espaço em branco, insira o código do caractere `&nbsp;`:

```
$resultado .= '<dd class="col-sm-9">' . $row_user['cidade'] . '&nbsp;' . $row_user['estado'] . '</dd>';
```

Comment: Andre
Realmente faltou as aspas simples , resolvido o problema
Grato